# bootstrap 4 accordion loading dynamically in the angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 accordion for my angular project. this is the my accordion

```
   <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
                        <div class="card mb-0">
                            <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
                                <a class="card-title float-none">
                                   Tank Id
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                              Tank Description
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                                href="#collapseTwo">
                                <a class="card-title float-none">
                                    Tank Id
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                                Tank Description
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

currently this is working well. but now I need to load accordion header and content according to below json array.

```
    {
"tanks":[
{
"id":"KT025",
"description":"kt025 is large tank with the 3 doors",
 
},
{
"id":"KT023",
"description":"kt023 is medium tank with the 2 doors",
},
{
"id":"KT034",
"description":"kt034 is small tank with the 2 doors",
}
]
}
```

how i do this, if you can big help? is it possible according my data?

Comment: Have a look in the Angular built in loop directive: https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#listing-items-with-ngfor
It helps you with your use case.

Answer (score 0):

As per your object and given detail you can do this.
You can refer to ng-repeat directive [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) in detail.

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main">
<div ng-repeat="n in object;">
  <div id="accordion" class="accordion" ng-repeat="k in n">
                        <div class="card mb-0">
                            <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
                                <a class="card-title float-none">
                                   Tank Id {{k.id}}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                              Tank Description {{k.description}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function Main($scope){
  $scope.object =  {
                    "tanks":[
                            {
                            "id":"KT025",
                            "description":"kt025 is large tank with the 3 doors",
                             
                            },
                            {
                            "id":"KT023",
                            "description":"kt023 is medium tank with the 2 doors",
                            },
                            {
                            "id":"KT034",
                            "description":"kt034 is small tank with the 2 doors",
                            }
                            ]
                   }
};
```

Comment: div ids should be dynamic ? is not it ?